# Does this DateTime code do anything different to DateTime.now

Tags: c#

I've come across the following method in some inherited legacy code.   It feels like it should be replace-able with a simple "**return DateTime.Now**".  However it seems so obvious that I don't want to make the change in-case I'm missing some hidden intent of this code.

```
public static DateTime GetTimeStamp() 
{
   return new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Ticks); 
}
```

My guess is that at the time the implementer mistaken thought that "DateTime.Now" returned a reference rather than a new instance but has anyone ever come across this or know a real reason it could have been implemented this way.

Comment: `DateTime` is an immutable class, so reference vs. new instance is irreleveant.

Comment: I assume that your fellow originally wanted to return something else. Or he wants to have the ability to change the implementation. However, he could have returned `DateTime.Now` instead.

Comment: I have heard some people believe doing it the way you mention above is more precise. I have a hard time believing that though.

Comment: Yes. You can just return `return DateTime.Now.Ticks`

Comment: @sll: He want the `DateTime` not the ticks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the same as DateTime.Now. Getting the ticks from a DateTime and putting it in the constructor will give you the same datetime:

[msdn => DateTime(int64 ticks)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2xf7zzk.aspx)

However you can lose the time zone awareness from DateTime.Now:

```
The Kind property is initialized to Unspecified.

For applications in which portability of date and time data or a limited degree of time zone awareness is important, you can use the corresponding DateTimeOffset constructor.
```

Comment: The remarks section tells that it uses [`Kind.Unspecified`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shx7s921.aspx) whereas [`DateTime.Now`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx) uses [`Kind.Local`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shx7s921.aspx) .

Comment: Thank you, have to love stack overflow.  It would have been so easy just to remove it thinking it was just strange coding.  But with the size of the code base and the lack of tests (which is what I'm adding)  it's impossible to say whether something calling it is going to be dependent upon "kind" being one value or the other.